# WPDB SQL query SELECT from category

Tags: wpdb, sql

I wrote SQL query to get items ID with 'instock' status, but don't know how to add to SELECT only from specified product category.

My code:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value LIKE 'instock' 
" );
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using WP_Query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are find products by specified category. Please find below code :

```
$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships ON ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id) 
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value LIKE 'instock' 
    AND {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 'cat 1', 'cat 2', 'cat 3' ) 
" );
```

**Note :** You need to replace "cat 1", "cat 2" and "cat 3" with your category.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use $wpdb :

```
$results = $wpdb->get_col( 
  $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts as p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
    AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = %d
  ", $cat_id)
);
```

If you would like to select by category name instead of ID, you have to join one more table:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_col( 
  $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts as p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms as t ON t.term_id = tr.object_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
    AND t.name %LIKE% %s
  ", $wpdb->esc_like($cat_name) )
);
```

**However, the preferred method for querying products, is this:**

```
$products = wc_get_products( array(
  'category' => array( 'shirts' ),
  'stock_status' => 'instock',
  'status' => 'publish',
));
```

[wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)